# Stop bluetooth audio from autoplaying when headphones reconnect to the computer

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, autoplay

I've a set of wireless headphones connected to my computer, which auto switch to my phone when I receive a call.

The problem is that when the call ends and the headphones reconnected to the computer, whatever I had on pause, will start playing again.

I want to resume playing manually, not automatically, as sometimes I'll leave a video or audiobook on hold on purpose and it's quite annoying to search through all the apps or browser tabs trying to find what's playing.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: this does happen on YouTube and Udemy, both on Firefox and Chrome. And also on SMPlayer, but not on Audacious, which I find odd.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: Hi, thank you for asking. I'm running Kubuntu 20.04. I'm not sure if that makes a difference. I've been on Linux for less than a year and I'm not aware of the differences.